# How to install GEOS on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

Can a kind soul help me install this dependence on Ubuntu?
https://trac.osgeo.org/geos/

I'm still learning how to use Ubuntu and have no idea where to click or what to do. And I haven't found any tutorials online.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 : Your link points to https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=geos&searchon=sourcenames&suite=all&section=all  → → https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/geos → → https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&searchon=names&keywords=libgeos

Comment: My bad, I mistyped, It is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

How would I go about installing these packages?

Comment: add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntugis/ppa && apt-get install -y libgeos++-dev   .... should do the trick

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suggest that you install with the terminal:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libgeos++-dev libgeos3.10.2 libgeos-c1v5 libgeos-dev libgeos-doc
```

Several dependencies may also be installed.

Note: libgeos might be available in different versions, you can find out which is available using `sudo apt search libgeos`

Comment: 3.10 is not available on Focal Fossa

Answer (score 1):

The **version 3.9.1** is the available version for Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal Fossa).

Also you need to install some dependencies **libgeos++-dev**, **libgeos-c1v5**, **libgeos-dev** and **libgeos-doc**.

Some dependencies can be optional, but recommended.

You can install the following package version on the repository:

`sudo apt install libgeos++-dev libgeos-3.9.1 libgeos-c1v5 libgeos-dev libgeos-doc`

Comment: Welcome! Other then the version, how is this any different to the answer above?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @JamesT I just updated and clarified the answer. Also there was a typo in the command. Also I edited the "@chili55" answer.

Comment: i like this answer better because it tells me what version of geos i'm about to get